# Mongoose.js: why can not re/set entire value of subdocument?

Tags: mongoose

Say I have a schema:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    youtube: {
        id_: false,
        video: {
            _id: false,
            ytId: 'string',
            ytState: 'string',
        },     
    }
})
```

I find some doc and want to set it's vidoe value.

If I try to set the whole object value:

```
doc.youtube.video = {ytId: xxx, ytState: xxx}
```

after save the video field (subdoc) is not changed, it got only changed after I set all fields directly

```
doc.youtube.video.ytId = xxx
doc.youtube.video.ytState = xxx
```

I wonder If someone could explain my why it works that way?

Comment: I'm not certain on why it's not working. I do it all the time. It might be a JavaScript issue more than a Node.js issue. Immediately after you set the video values, do a console.log(doc.youtube.video) and check if the values have been stored

Comment: I've posted this kind of issue on github, you may try the code https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1394

Comment: I'll try it out over the weekend if I get some time